# Enforce an action to be called before another using Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Recently I did that for one app and I'd like to know if this would be considered a *bad practice* or if it is ok. Let's say I have a reducer listening for two actions:

```
switch (action.type) {
  case 'PRE_FETCH_ACTION':
    return Object.assign({}, state, {value: action.value, isAllowed: true})
  case 'FETCHED_SUCCESS':
    if (!state.isAllowed) {
      throw Error('You did not dispatch PRE_FETCH_ACTION before fetching!');
    }
    return Object.assign({}, state, {data: action.data, isAllowed: false})
}
```

So the flow is:

- I dispatch `PRE_FETCH_ACTION`
- I make a fetch call to an external API
- When the service response returns, it dispatches `FETCHED_SUCCESS`

If somebody tries to fetch data without dispatching the `PRE_FETCH_ACTION`first, the code will throw an error.

Ok, so this works just fine. My concern is, as I said, if this would be considered a bad pattern. Why do I think so? Because the `isAllowed` piece of state is kinda internal to the reducer and it does not affect any component render method.

Comment: If it does not break the application, I would just simply ignore Actions that are irrelevant to the current state, such as `FETCHED_SUCCESS`. You could display a warning, as it is a design oversight to wait for a request to finish that wasn't even initated, but I certainly wouldn't `throw`.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's ok to have such "technical" flags in your app state.

In your case you want to ensure that actions are dispatched in a specific order, which defines a particular behavior of your app (for example, displaying a loader on the screen when data-fetching starts). That's why I think your "technical" flag eventually manages your UI.

To let your reducer "reduce only", you could make your check before dispatching, by testing your state in action creator. This pattern is detailed in Redux's doc about [async actions](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html). You would do it in a "thunk" action creator that you would call instead of calling sync action "fetchedSuccess", like this:

```
function toFetchedSuccess(data) {  // "thunk" action creator
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        const state = getState();  // current state
        if(!state.isAllowed) {
            console.error(
                'You did not dispatch PRE_FETCH_ACTION before fetching!');
            return Promise.resolve();  // nothing to do
        } else {
            return dispatch(fetchedSuccess(data));
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Can you show me how would yo do what you suggest in your last statement? By the way, all my actions are bound using ```const boundActionCreators = bindActionCreators(actions, this.props.dispatch);
``` and then passed via props.

Comment: I just added corresponding details to my answer.